# Dynamic categories with docpad

Tags: docpad

I have the following posts in my blog :

**src/documents/posts/foo.html.md**

```
---
category: cooking
---
```

**src/documents/posts/bar.html.md**

```
---
category: programmation
---
```

I would like to generate the following routes :

```
http://example.org/cooking/
http://example.org/programmation/
```

Where each route would have a collection with only posts in the selected category. The posts would still be in the standard place :

```
http://example.org/posts/foo.html
http://example.org/posts/bar.html
```

**Bonus point :** I would also like to be able to list categories in my layout. Something like :

```
<% for cat in @getCategories() %>
    <a href="<%= cat.route %>"><%= cat.name %></a>
<% endfor %>
```

---

Is there a plugin already existing which give these kind of functionalities ? If not, what's the best way to starting implementing it ?

I have seen the `setFilter` method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353716/how-to-query-documents-in-docpad-based-on-arrays-of-objects), but I'm still struggling to find out how to generate new pages after parsing every posts to fetch categories.

If dynamic page generation cannot be achieved (which I could understand, since it would require to parse pages in a specific order), would having a static array in the configuration make it easier ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this related plugin :

https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-related

As far as I know it doesn't generate tags pages automatically for you, but that's a good start.

Comment: You can also generate tag pages automatically by using the [tags plugin](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-tags)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this same thing with a tags plug-in: https://github.com/rantecki/docpad-plugin-tagging

It automagically creates views for each tag you use. Listing the categories is pretty simple as well. Here's what I've got, using a select box:

```
<select ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="">Choose</option>
<% for tag, data of @getTagCloud(): %>
<option value="<%= data.url %>">
<%= tag %>
</option>
<% end %>
</select>
```